# Create sliding panel similar to Google Maps left-side navigation

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, html, visual-studio-2010

I need to code out a left side panel that look exactly like Google Map
[image]

For instance when I press the arrow, it will minimize the left side panel.

[image]

So when I click the arrow it will appear again and my content will move to the right.

Any help?

Comment: You can look into jQuery's `show` and `hide` methods.  Might be a good start.

Comment: `$().toggle()` is your friend.

Answer (score 3):

It is really easy to implement. Of course my implemataion will be ugly, but you just need to change css. Full code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/YDukt/
HTML looks like below:

```
<div id='leftSide'>
    Something here from google
</div>
<div id='click'>
    >
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#click').click(function()
{
    $("#leftSide").animate({width:'toggle'},500);       
});
```

And the ugly CSS:

```
#leftSide
{
     height: 500px;
     width: 200px;
     background: black;
     float: left;
     display: none;    
     color: white;
     font-size: xx-large;
}
#click
{
     height: 25px;
     width: 25px;
     background: aqua;
     float: left; 
     margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Hi, don't seem to be able to work because i lack of the jquery.js.

Comment: what framework you use instead of jquery? or why you could not use jquery?

Comment: I have this following code     <div id="Map">

        </div> which will give me a map picture but somehow the arrow isn't inside the map